# Autofill "error 400" when applying code twice

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

When performing an autofill operation on a certain sheet my code works fine. Except when I also want to perform the same operation on another fill I get an "error 400" I can't figure out why.

This works fine:

```
Sheets(2).Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(9, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(7 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

But this gives an error:

```
Sheets(7).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(7 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheets(2).Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(9, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(7 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The solution

```
Sheets(7).Range(Sheets(7).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(7).Cells(2, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(7).Range(Sheets(7).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(7).Cells(7 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(9, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(9, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(9, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(7 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Try specifying which sheet every range or cell object is refering to. If nothing is used it will use the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Thank you, should have seen it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a better solution.

```
dim ws3 as worksheet
set ws3 = Worksheets(3)

with Worksheets(7)
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 4 + ws3.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).AutoFill _
      Destination:=.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(7 + ws3.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4 + ws3.UsedRange.Columns.Count)), Type:=xlFillDefault
end with

with Worksheets(2)
    .Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(9, 4 + ws3.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).AutoFill _
      Destination:=.Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(7 + ws3.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4 + Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count)), Type:=xlFillDefault
end with

set ws3 = Nothing
```

The [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) eaasily assigns worksheet parentage to any [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) or [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) by simply prefacing the `.Range` or `.Cells` with a period (aka `.` or *full stop*).